# Get the probability of a twitter feed going viral

Tags: r, machine-learning, python, predictive-models

For a given tweet, I need to determine the probability of it going viral. I have given this a thought and have considered various attributes like the sentiment, number of followers, time of post, length of the post, number of hashtags. But I am not sure on how to proceed.

Is there a given framework, already prepared models that could be used to determine the virality of the given feed? I would also like to extend this idea to Facebook feeds and other blog feeds.

Comment: There are indeed many frameworks for virality and diffusion that include Twitter but are not limited to that. Among the best papers analyzing tweets is Watts and Hofman *The Structural Virality of Online Diffusion*, unfortunately it doesn't appear to be ungated. Then there's Watts and Goldstein's *The Structure of Online Diffusion Networks* which is ungated (http://www.dangoldstein.com/papers/goel_watts_goldstein_diffusion_ec2012.pdf). Finally, Lana Adamic's video discusses a framework for thinking about *FB* cascades that is generalizable ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bA0Gin1t0m0

Comment: @DJohnson Could you point me to any framework? Like Google's tensorflow already has a pre-trained model for image recognition. Is there one for virality too? Or is there any framework using which I could build on?

Comment: Framework? By that are you referring to something like point and click software or an R module? Or are you referring to behavioral, mechanical, scientific and/or statistical assumptions underlying/driving viral diffusion processes?

Comment: @DJohnson Some R module

Answer (score 2):

There is some interesting meta research on this topic in regards to high impact academic papers. Schilling and Green (2011) came up with a few models describing what makes a paper high impact. For a direct look at tweets, there is the Jenders et al. (2013) paper that uses machine learning to predict viral tweets. I believe they used a naive bayes model.

Those two papers, and looking at what work has cited them, should give you a really good start on the modeling techniques used to look at high impact pieces of literature/media.

Jenders, M., Kasneci, G., & Naumann, F. (2013, May). Analyzing and predicting viral tweets. In Proceedings of the 22nd international conference on World Wide Web (pp. 657-664). ACM.

Schilling, M. A., & Green, E. (2011). Recombinant search and breakthrough idea generation: An analysis of high impact papers in the social sciences. Research Policy, 40(10), 1321-1331.